# In AWS how to migrate "Microsoft Windows Server 2016" server instance to "Microsoft Windows Server 2016 with SQL Server 2017 Standard "?

Tags: windows, server, sql-server-2017, windows-server-2016

Currently I have "Microsoft Windows Server 2016" instance running in AWS where I have installed evaluation version of SQL server 2017. Now I want to move this server along with SQL database to "Microsoft Windows Server 2016 with SQL Server 2017 Standard" AMI.

What are the necessary steps to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how you move from the Evaluation Licence to a paid Standard Licence? Buy the licences you require and the register them. [Upgrade to a Different Edition of SQL Server (Setup)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-to-a-different-edition-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: No. I don't want to proceed that way.We don't want to monitor license expiry and all so we want to use AWS AMI which will have SQL server 2017 installed in it.So that we don;t have to worry about license expiry.

Comment: SQL Server licences don't expire, apart fro. evaluation. If you don't want to pay for the licences, you can use Express however the functionality is far more limited. Either way, you *have* to either purchase an edition or switch to express. Alternatively you'll need to go down a hosted method, which I am sure AWS offer.